# Working example of jeditable and autocomplete working together with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, autocomplete, jeditable

I see a lot of google/stack overflow posts on jeditable and autocomplete working together but i can't find the way to validate them. Does anyone know of a working version of jeditable and autocomplete functionality working together with validation. Please help! Here is a simple example:

```
$.editable.addInputType('autocomplete', {
    element : $.editable.types.text.element,
    plugin : function(settings, original) {
        $('input', this).autocomplete(settings.autocomplete.data);
    }
});

$(".autocomplete").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php";, {
    type      : "autocomplete",
    tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
    onblur    : "submit",
    autocomplete : {
        multiple : true,
        data     : ["Aberdeen", "Ada", "Adamsville", "Addyston", "Adelphi", "Adena", "Adrian", "Akron"]
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having the same problem.